# How to select all checkboxes in telerik.grid used in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Telerik grid. I have one column as checkbox .I want to select all checkbox in single header click or any click action how can i do that in Telerik.grid using  asp.net mvc technology

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Assign", "Application", new { id = Model.ID,redirectto=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery }))
       { %> 

    <b>SelectAll</b><input type="checkbox" name="checkrecord" title="Records"  />
          <% Html.Telerik().Grid<ResourceKit.DataModel.Terminology>().Name("Terminology")
                  .BindTo((IEnumerable<ResourceKit.DataModel.Terminology>)ViewData["Terminology"])

                 .Columns(columns =>
                     {
                         columns.Template(term =>
            {
                %>
                    <input name="checkedRecords" type="checkbox" value="<%=
                       term.ID %>" title="checkedRecords"  />
                <%
            }).Title("Select").Width(40).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });

                         columns.Bound(term => term.Name);

                     }).Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(20)
                       .Position(GridPagerPosition.Both).Style(pagerStyles))
                       .Sortable()
                       .Scrollable()
                       .Filterable()
                       .Render(); 
                  %>
                  <p>
                    <input type="button" value="Associate" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
                </p>
    <% } %>
```

I have code like this Per page 20 records displayed,i have select all checkbox on click of that I have to select all checkboxes in side the grid.

Comment: You really need to post some code and HTML if you want to get a specific answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can

```
$('#element-id').click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    this.checked = true;
  });
});
```

But you need to provide your code and HTML to get a more specific answer.